# Crontab backup not working (not generating log)

Tags: bash, backup, cron

I want to run a script every day at a certain hour, so I saw that I could use `cron` for that.

Following the tutorial, I edited the `crontab` file like this: `crontab -e` and added:

```
26 13 * * * ./home/user/backup.sh && echo "Backup done: $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" >> /home/user/log.txt
```

13:26 was 2 minutes ago, however in /home/user there is no log.txt

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you run in terminal:

```
./home/user/backup.sh
```

you will get probably an error like:

```
bash: ./home/user/backup.sh: No such file or directory
```

That because in this case is not correct to use that `.` (dot) in front of the path to the scipt (`/home/user/backup.sh`). Also be sure that `backup.sh` is executable by running:

```
chmod +x /home/user/backup.sh
```

And also, be sure that you chage `user` with your user name everywhere.

And finally, be sure that the exit status of `/home/user/backup.sh` script is 0. If the exit status is different by 0, the second command (`echo "Backup done: $(date +"\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S")"` - where you have to escape all `%` characters) will never be executed because of [`&&` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of).

As I said, you have to escape all `%` (percent) in a crontab entry because it has a special meaning in this case:

> Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`),
>   are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first %
>   are sent to the command as standard input.
>
> <sup>Source: [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)</sup>

Comment: `backup.sh` is indeed executable. However, right now I am testing this I am programming just the echo. This doesn't work: `*/1 * * * * echo "Executed backup: $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" >> /home/user/log.txt`
`However, this does work: */1 * * * * echo "test every minute" >> /home/user/log2.txt`

Comment: The backslashes before the double quote marks don't work either. It feels like it is impossible to echo the damn formatted date.

Comment: `/bin/echo` does not work either

Comment: @dabadaba Forget what I said about /bin/echo. Just now I tested and, as DK Bose said, all % need to be escaped.